# Create a folder with the email of the user that just created an account and display the image(s) that is in the user email's folder using php

Tags: php, email, directory, filenames, subdirectory

i wrote a php code for, when a new user creates an account on a website, a folder is automatically created with the user email address as the folder name, Now there is an image in the folder(i.e `C://localhost/vern/mikelawson@gmail.com/zeco/image.jpg`).

Note: There is a code that removes the @gmail.com
(i.e `C://localhost/vern/mikelawson/zeco/image.jpg`).

Am trying to display the image from the user(mikelawson@gmail.com) folder, but it is not displaying.

it keeps displaying the image that is from the first user(mikelawson@gmail.com) folder.

```
The code below is for creating the folder:
```

```
// Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $nest = $email; 

    if ($user['email'] !== $email) {
      $userfname = substr($email, 0, strpos($email, '@'));
      (!mkdir($userfname, 0777, true));
    }

    $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, user_number, password) 
              VALUES('$username', '$email', '$user_number', '$password')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
    header('location: index.php');
  }
```

```
The below is for displaying the image(s):
```

```
$email = "";


$base_url = 'http://localhost/vern/';
$userfname = substr($email, 0, strpos($email, '@'));
$dir = $userfname."*/zeco/*";

$files = glob($dir);
usort( $files, function( $a, $b ) { return filemtime($b) - filemtime($a); } );
$i = 1;
foreach($files as $file) {
$remove_ext = substr($file, 0, strrpos($file, "."));
  if($i <= 1 AND $i >= 1){
    echo '<img src="'.$base_url.$file.'" alt="'.$remove_ext.'" style="width:45px;height:45px;border-radius:10px;"></br>';
  }
 $i++;
}
```

I expected the output to be:

```
img src="http://localhost/vern/mikelawson/zeco/pouvoir 046.jpg" 
alt="mikelawson/zeco/pouvoir 046" "
```

not this:

```
img src="http://localhost/mikelawson/zeco/pouvoir 046.jpg" 
alt="mikelawson/zeco/pouvoir 046""
```

Answer (score 0):

How do You set the $email variable? Because I don't see anything in the piece of code that You wrote.
Place also (before foreach):

```
var_dump($files);
```

And paste the output